# Jackrabbit localhost server in silex

Tags: silex, jackrabbit

I am doing a sample project in silex to store the uploaded files into a jackrabbit server using **marmelab/phpcr-api-silex-provider** and my composer.json file looks like as follows

```
{   
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.1",
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "twig/twig": "~1.14",
        "jackalope/jackalope-jackrabbit": "~1.0",
        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "~1.0",
        "marmelab/phpcr-api-silex-provider": "~1.1"
    }

}
```

But i don't know how to install jackrabbit server for the file storage in my local machine.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to install the server? I've never worked with the jackrabbit software, but from its [docs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/getting-started-with-apache-jackrabbit.html) it's pretty straight forward, just [download the jar file](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html) and then you just have to [invoke it](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/standalone-server.html): ```$ java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-X.Y.Z.jar```. What have you tried? Where does it fail? Which error does it gives you?

Comment: Actually my machine was showing some kind of error, eventually it was due to some permissions issue

Comment: Ok Rejith, glad you work it out. In your future questions try to put the output error that you get when something fails :-)

Comment: Ok Torres, I will make sure of that.Thank you